# Passing ranks to different buffers?

Tags: shapefile, r, vector, buffer

I have a SpatialPointsDataFrame which refers to a city.I needed to perform a join with a dbf in order to attach the population column which i did with help from a couple of people from here. Next step is to take the settlements that contain population under 1000 people and perform the corresponding buffers of 500 and pass it the 0 rank, the 500 through 1000 and pass it the 5 rank and the >1000 and pass it the 10 rank.
i have to do the same for the rest of the population.

The problem here is that if i give 1000 to the rest of the city outside of the two buffers, what i'm going to do with the other 10's of more than 1500 and more than 5000.

If anyone has any idea feel free to say.

Here's my effort

```
cit<-readShapeSpatial("shp")
df1 <- read.dbf("2013Kpopulation.dbf") #import of dbf
m<-merge(cit,df1,by.x="COS",by.y="JDS") #join in order to make the "cit" contain the population
settlem.a1<-gBuffer(m[m$2013Kpopulation<1000,],width=500,byid=T) #500 buffer for under 1000 as the table says
settlem.a2<-gBuffer(m[m$2013Kpopulation<1000,],width=1000,byid=T) #1000 buffer for under 1500
settlem.a1$rank<-0 #
settlem.a2$rank<-5
m$rank<-10
```

Here's the table

```
               Population of cities        Distances     Ranks
                                             <500          0
                       < 1000               500-1000       5
                                             >1000         10

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                            <750           0
                      1000-5000            750-1500        5
                                            >1500          10
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                            <1500          0
                      > 5000               1500-5000       5
                                            >5000          10
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and add a sketch diagram of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: i believe if you read carefully the question and the table you will understand it, i cant make it more clear.